# How do I make XCode open files to the right?

Tags: xcode

When I double click on files in my left file panel in XCode while developing my iPhone application, they open in new windows.

I want them to open in the right main area. How do I set that feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking how to make it appear on the right instead of pop up? or asking how to change the behavior?

I'm not on a Mac right now, but if I remembered correctly, that is the behavior when you double-click instead of single-click. Just single-click on the file and it should load on the code panel.

But if your question is how to change the behavior, I don't believe you can. But again I'm not on a Mac right now so I don't have a definite answer.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will just single click. Thanks!